# Did RamaKrishna bless Rupa Goswami in his previous life?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, ramakrishna

I remember reading a story about how Ramakrishna in his previous life had blessed gaudiya vaishnava saint rupa goswami. That is a book in my local language and had small introduction to over 60 spiritual people that lived.

I can't recollect that book's name(I read many such books in childhood & I don't have those books now).

Do followers of RamaKrishna believe this story? If yes, what are the details of the story?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no existence of such an existence in any of the authentic books on Sri Ramakrishna.

This incident is NOT found in any of the authentic books on Sri Ramakrishna:

**A. The books written by His direct disciples and published by the Ramakrishna Mission:**

1.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Kathamrita by M

2.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Leelaprasanga by Swami Saradananda

3.Sri Ramaktprishnadeva by Sasibhushan Ghosh

4.Sri Sri Ramakrishnadever Jivanbrittanta by Ramchandra Dutta

5.Sri Ramakrishna-Puthi by Akshay Kumar Sen

6.Sri SrinRamakrishnadever Upadesha by Swami Brahmananda

**B. The books written by disciples of Sri Ramakrishna, but not published by the Mission:**

7.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Leelamrita by Vaikunthanath Sannyal

8.Sri Sri Ramakrishnadever Upadesh by Suresh Chandra Dutta

So this is surely some story constructed by someone.